# what data type should I use for storing small decimal value

Tags: t-sql

what data type should I use to store small decimal value? Ranging from `-50.00` to `50.00`?

Thanks,

Comment: I am considering using smallmoney, is it a reasonable choice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `DECIMAL(4,2)` which would allow you to store -99.99 to 99.99

[MSDN documentation for DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).
The 4 represents the precision which is the total number of digits that can be stored (to the left and right of the decimal place).
The 2 represents the scale which is the number of digits that can appear after the decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Basically you need two points before the decimal and 2 after?

```
columnname precision(4)
```